# webElement.getAttribute() is not working in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium for automating test cases for web application in that I have to get tool tip text

I tried

```
String result =element.getAttribute("span");
```

but this is retuning null. how can I get the text ?

Comment: Can you show use the HTML you're trying to manipulate? Also, what language are you using?

Comment: hi am using java. and my code is                                         <span id="source-location-help-text" class="field-description-placeholder" style="display: none;">
For Unix, IP address must be configured which can be optionally appended with the relative path. E.g.,
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: inherit;">131.1.1.1/files</span>.<br>
For windows either IP Address or system ID can be configured which can be optionally appended with the relative path.
</span>
</span> i want to get this text "For Unix, IP address must be configured which can be optionally ..........."

Comment: I've told you this before, paste your HTML code not in the comments, but in your question. Please learn to edit your questions. I will remove the down-vote one you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.getAttribute("span");
```

`span` must not be an attribute of the given element. I guess you've misunderstood, the `getAttribute()` method.

For e.g.

```
<a href="http://example.com" title="Example Site">Example</a>
```

For the above anchor tag, in order to get the title attributes' value, you can use :

```
element.getAttribute("title");
```

where element refers to the above anchor element.

Comment: you can refer [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) for more info..

Comment: thanks for ur help i got the solution i have used getAttribute("innerHTML") to retrieve my text                           thanks again